# How to place two divs aligned

Tags: css, html, alignment

```
<div id="divT">divT</div>
<div id="divL">
<br><br>
<div id="person">Person</div>
<div id="father">Father</div>
</div>
<div id="divR">divR</div>
```

css

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
}
#divT{
    width:100%;
    background:blue;
}
#divL{
    display:inline-block;
    width:14%;
    height:100%;
    background:#008080;
}
#divR{
    display:inline-block;
    width:79%;
    background:#e1e1e1;
}
```

Why `divR` has top and left margins ? I don't want them.

fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GzRp9/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `float:right` and set the `width` to `86%` in `#divR`

```
#divR
{
    width:86%;
    background:#e1e1e1;
    float:right;
}
```

Here's the jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/FcDsk/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GzRp9/2/)</kbd>

It doesn't have margins. Since it is a `display:inline-block` element, the top spacing comes from it needing to be vertically aligned to the top, and the left spacing comes from the literal space between it and the `<div>` element before it.

Add this:

```
#divR
{
    /* ... */
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

And remove the space between `#divL` and `#divR`.

Comment: 46 seconds to slow :( darn

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `vertical-align:top` to your rules for `#divR`.

```
#divR {
    display:inline-block;
    width:79%;
    background:#e1e1e1;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GzRp9/8/)**

The default value for vartical-align is baseline and you needed top instead.

Comment: Don't forget about the space to the left of `#divR`.

Comment: @AlexMorrise - yup I see you noted that in your answer so I won't duplicate that in mine since the OP can figure it out from yours.

Comment: I just mention it for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `vertical-align: top` will remove the top space, which is not a margin but a gap.

And removing the space between the div and the previous one will remove the left space. This is because inline-block elements will render the spaces left in the code

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, adding `vertical-align: top;` to #divR will fix the top issue. My personal favorite fix for white space is to set the parent's font-size to 0 and restore it in the element that has the fonts itself.

In the case of the fiddle:

```
body {
    font-size: 0;
}
#divT{
    font-size: 14px;
}
#divL{
    font-size: 14px;
}
#divR{
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GzRp9/7/

Comment: I like it. My only issue with this is that you have to change the font-size in multiple places if you want to make an adjustment.

Comment: Right, it's that or floating. In my opinion, this method makes website building that much more intentional..

Comment: Good point. And if you're using a CSS pre-compiler like LESS it's definitely the way to go.